# Plotting figures using 'par(mfrow=c())' in R

Tags: r, plot

I have 3 figures of which I would like to plot in the same place in R. I would like to have 2 columns, which would make the 3rd figure plotted alone in the second row. Using `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` functions in R, is there a way to have the bottom figure plotted in the centre of the plot, as opposed to underneath the top figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using `par(mfrow = ...)`

However, you can use `layout()`.

Try this:

```
par(mai=rep(0.5, 4))
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:20)
plot(1:30)
```

[image]

So you can see the idea is to create a matrix where each cell indicates which graph to plot. You can extend the logic as follows:

```
par(mai=rep(0.5, 4))
layout(matrix(c(1,1, 2,2, 0, 3,3, 0), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:20)
plot(1:30)
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have the bottom figure not so stretched out? I.e. the same dimensions as the top two figures, but simply positioned in the centre? Cheers

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I'm needing. Thank you!